# Docker - Multi or Single Container?

Tags: docker

With Docker, which is a better scenario in general? I always favorited the singularity of a container, but please advise. Below, I use an example of a simple PHP setup.

> I don't know the best terminology for the container strategy (?), but I'll do my best with the title and I hope it's self-explanatory.

--

> ** Pretend the setup is a single server, with a few applications.  **

**(A) Single Responsibility Containers**

1. Docker Apache2
2. Docker PHP
3. Docker PHP (Other Project #2)
4. Docker PHP (Other Project #3)

**(B) Mult Responsibility Containers**

1. Docker All (Apache / PHP)

   1. In the above, does one place every **project** within one container?

      - *I know you can setup repositories outside of the container, but that's is not what I want to do.*
   2. Or, does one create a container **per project**?

I don't like the idea of having everything mucked up into one container which is why I ask, yet I see full-fledged LAMP containers.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This question too generic and leave too much space for interpretation. Are you having a specific problem  you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PHP and Apache httpd, you can go with the [official PHP Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), create a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to stitch together the PHP container with your PHP source in one image. Probably you will need a database container which will be a separate image (eg. mariadb). To create a stack for your app use [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). Put altogether into a private or public git repository and your are good to go.

If you do it that way, you will get reproducible images per project which will be completely independent and you can roll back at any time.

During development you can just mount (`docker run -v`) your PHP source to the PHP container for rapid development. The image build, as described above, will be the last step for a roll out.